# Вращение колёсика мышки С++ MSVS Консольное приложение OpenGl glut

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, консоль, glut

Как работать с колёсиком мышки в консольном проекте (Окно создается при помощи библиотеки glut) С++?

```
int main() 
{ 
  glutInit(&argc,argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);
  glutInitWindowSize(800,450);
  glutInitWindowPosition(20,20);
  id_win = glutCreateWindow("Loader");
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutMouseFunc(Mouse);
  glutPassiveMotionFunc(MAUS_PassiveMotionFunc);
  glutMotionFunc(MausMot);
  glutReshapeFunc(size);
  GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(scr);
  glClearColor(0.33,0.33,0.33, 0);
  glutTimerFunc(0,Timer,0);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
 }
```

Если стандартным методом это невозможно, Что можно предпринять?

Comment: Что за консоль opengl? Что за консоль C++?

Comment: я создаю програмы (игры) с использованием OpenGL. для этого я изначально создаю консольный проект а та уже прописываю создание окана с помощю glut и все остальное

Comment: "Консольный проект" никак не обязан быть "консольным". Это просто для удобства создания нового проекта в IDE сделано.

Comment: Хорошо не совсем консольный glut создает окно, как можно отледить (среагировать) на смещение колесика мышки?

Comment: Так отредактируйте свой вопрос и заголовок, опишите, что вы делаете и что хотите получить в итоге. Лучше еще добавить код того, что вы сейчас делаете для создания окна.

Comment: Отредактирую вопрос, заголовок оставлю, думаю не только я именно так в поисковике формулирую.

Comment: int main()
{
 ///glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,450);
    glutInitWindowPosition(20,20);
    id_win = glutCreateWindow("Loader");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(Mouse);
 glutPassiveMotionFunc(MAUS_PassiveMotionFunc);
 glutMotionFunc(MausMot);
 glutReshapeFunc(size);

 GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(scr);

    glClearColor(0.33,0.33,0.33, 0);

 

 glutTimerFunc(0,Timer,0);
    glutMainLoop();

 return 0;
}

Comment: В заголовке, возможно, стоит упомянуть glut. А _консоль opengl_ это абсурд какой-то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glut очень устаревшая библиотека и этой функции здесь нет нужно использовать glew glfw оно того стоит

вот пример Всего что можно получить от мышки

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

static void cursorPositionCallback( GLFWwindow *window, double xpos, double ypos );
void cursorEnterCallback( GLFWwindow *window, int entered );
void mouseButtonCallback( GLFWwindow *window, int button, int action, int mods );
void scrollCallback( GLFWwindow *window, double xoffset, double yoffset );


int main( void )
{
    GLFWwindow *window;

    // Initialize the library
    if ( !glfwInit( ) )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Hello World", NULL, NULL );

    glfwSetCursorPosCallback( window, cursorPositionCallback );
    glfwSetInputMode( window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_NORMAL );

    glfwSetCursorEnterCallback( window, cursorEnterCallback );

    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback( window, mouseButtonCallback );
    glfwSetInputMode( window, GLFW_STICKY_MOUSE_BUTTONS, 1 );



    glfwSetScrollCallback( window, scrollCallback );

    unsigned char pixels[16 * 16 * 4];
    memset( pixels, 0xff, sizeof( pixels ) );
    GLFWimage image;
    image.width = 16;
    image.height = 16;
    image.pixels = pixels;
    GLFWcursor *cursor = glfwCreateCursor( &image, 0, 0 );
    glfwSetCursor( window, cursor ); // set to null to reset cursor

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize( window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight );

    if ( !window )
    {
        glfwTerminate( );
        return -1;
    }

    // Make the window's context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );

    glViewport( 0.0f, 0.0f, screenWidth, screenHeight ); // specifies the part of the window to which OpenGL will draw (in pixels), convert from normalised to pixels
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION ); // projection matrix defines the properties of the camera that views the objects in the world coordinate frame. Here you typically set the zoom factor, aspect ratio and the near and far clipping planes
    glLoadIdentity( ); // replace the current matrix with the identity matrix and starts us a fresh because matrix transforms such as glOrpho and glRotate cumulate, basically puts us at (0, 0, 0)
    glOrtho( 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 1 ); // essentially set coordinate system
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW ); // (default matrix mode) modelview matrix defines how your objects are transformed (meaning translation, rotation and scaling) in your world
    glLoadIdentity( ); // same as above comment


    // Loop until the user closes the window
    while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        // Render OpenGL here

        double xpos, ypos;
        glfwGetCursorPos( window, &xpos, &ypos );

        // Swap front and back buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers( window );

        // Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents( );
    }

    glfwTerminate( );

    return 0;
}

static void cursorPositionCallback( GLFWwindow *window, double xpos, double ypos )
{
    std::cout << xpos << " : " << ypos << std::endl;
}

void cursorEnterCallback( GLFWwindow *window, int entered )
{
    if ( entered )
    {
        std::cout << "Entered Window" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Left window" << std::endl;
    }
}

void mouseButtonCallback( GLFWwindow *window, int button, int action, int mods )
{
    if ( button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT && action == GLFW_PRESS )
    {
        std::cout << "Right button pressed" << std::endl;
    }
}

void scrollCallback( GLFWwindow *window, double xoffset, double yoffset )
{
    std::cout << xoffset << " : " << yoffset << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В консоли окно и его очередь консольной программе недоступны.

Подозреваю, что какими-то хакерскими штуками можно этот доступ получить, но это будет очень сложно.

Поэтому ответ - никак.

Comment: А нет ни каких функций из win api чтобы зарегистрировать функцыю куда будит приходить события смещения колёсика, glut по идее использует winAPI для создания окон.

Comment: Насколько я знаю - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>


class ConsoleModeSafeChangeMode
{
public:
    ConsoleModeSafeChangeMode(HANDLE handle, DWORD fdwNewMode) {
        m_hStdin = handle;
        if(!GetConsoleMode(m_hStdin, &m_fdwSaveOldMode)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("GetConsoleMode failed");
        }
        if (!SetConsoleMode(m_hStdin, fdwNewMode)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("SetConsoleMode failed");
        }
    }
    ~ConsoleModeSafeChangeMode() {
        //Восстанавливаем состояние
        SetConsoleMode(m_hStdin, m_fdwSaveOldMode);
    }
private:
    ConsoleModeSafeChangeMode(const ConsoleModeSafeChangeMode&) = delete;
    ConsoleModeSafeChangeMode &operator=(const ConsoleModeSafeChangeMode&) = delete;
    HANDLE m_hStdin;
    DWORD m_fdwSaveOldMode;
};



int main() 
{ 
    DWORD cNumRead, fdwMode, i; 
    INPUT_RECORD irInBuf[128]; 

    HANDLE hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    try {
        //Активируем события мыши
        ConsoleModeSafeChangeMode wrapper(hStdin, ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT);     
        while (true) 
        { 
            //Ждем событий
            if (!ReadConsoleInput(hStdin, irInBuf, 128, &cNumRead)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("ReadConsoleInput failed");
            }
            for (i = 0; i < cNumRead; i++) 
            {
                switch(irInBuf[i].EventType) 
                { 
                    case MOUSE_EVENT:
                        if (irInBuf[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwEventFlags == MOUSE_WHEELED)
                        {
                            short value = HIWORD(irInBuf[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState);
                            std::cout 
                                << "vertical mouse wheel " 
                                << ((value < 0)?"down":"up") 
                                << ": " 
                                << value 
                                << std::endl;
                        }
                        break;
                    case KEY_EVENT:
                        return 0;
                    default:
                        break;
                } 
            }
        } 
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Надеюсь, разберетесь. 
Пример побольше есть по ссылке: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events

Comment: В примере по ссылки сканер клавиатуры, работает но на мышку и колёсико не реагирует.

Comment: Старая VS? Необходима поддержка C++11. Для теста можете удалить   строки ConsoleModeSafeChangeMode(const ConsoleModeSafeChangeMode&) = delete; и 
    ConsoleModeSafeChangeMode &operator=(const ConsoleModeSafeChangeMode&) = delete;

Comment: в примере по ссылке и на мышку реагирует. Самолично собирал и пробовал.

Comment: но это всё для дефолтной windows-консоли

Comment: msvs 2010, мне нужно чтобы программа реагировала на вращения вне зависимости од фокуса на окне. У меня не реагирует на вращения. Дефолтная консоль? я создаю пустой проект.

Comment: тесть реагирует но в консолье просто перелистывает текст но это и без кода работает.

Comment: Я умею отслеживать нажатия клавиш вне зависимости от фокуса и нажатия кнопок мышки, мне нужно исключительно вращение.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476260/catch-global-mouse-scroll-and-send-custom-mouse-scroll-events-to-apps

Comment: Вы удалили комментарий с названием функции, Сбросте название ещё роз пожалуйста.